# Map generation when it is already in JPEG format

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I got maps in JPEG format but I need some information to be added in it. I can't start editing in JPEG format. If there is any other procedure to add other features into it. Then please let me know.

Comment: I think you can use the map as background raster image (probably will need georeferencing) and then you can add new layers and later create new layout. But of course, you will not be able to remove or modify existing data in the jpg map.

Answer (score 1):

I often get maps in an image format (usually a poorly aligned scan of a photocopy of a creased map that somebody drew on with crayons).

You have three options.  The first is to follow Juhele's advice to georefernece your map and use it as a raster backdrop to your new features.  The other option is to use GIMP or Photoshop if you want to do something simple like edit typos in the legend or add a couple of place-markers or a call-out balloon to describe a feature.

You're pretty much stuck with the layers that are already in the map you've been given, but if you MUST remove something, remember that it's just a raster and Arc has a whole slew of tools as do GIMP and Photoshop that will allow you to selectively change the appearance of a raster.  Just remember that everything is editable, but not all edits are advisable :)

The third option is to ask for the MXD file (assuming the person who provided you with the map uses Arc) and/or the raw data.  Then you can do what you like with it.